# how to flatten a PDF of embedded images with javascript

Tags: javascript, pdf, pdf-generation, jspdf

When saving a PDF from the screen from our web app, we use Google Chrome to save to PDF.
Steps

1. Command Print
2. Save a PDF

An alternative is to use the library jsPDF to create a PDF from the HTML contents and download it that way.

However the problem is when opening the downloaded PDF the images are embedded and the PDF is not completely flat. Example: https://github.com/Hopding/pdf-lib/blob/master/assets/pdfs/examples/embed_png_and_jpeg_images.pdf

How can I flatten the PDF completely to be one image. The result would be something like a scanned document from a physical scanner.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do you really want/need an image???

PDF has way more capabilities, also for long-time archiving, that saving as an image is the very last choice.

It would be preferrable to create a PDF/A compliant file. To do so, there are several tools on the market; which one would depend on your requirements.

Comment: Could you please help me here? https://stackoverflow.com/q/66950166/7785337

Comment: I need to be like a scanned PDF so flat