# Unable to select text from pdf

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pdf, pdf-generation, jspdf

I am making a simple ReactJS application for pdf generation.

**Libraries used:**

-> [jspdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jspdf)

-> [html2canvas](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html2canvas)

**index.js**

JSX:

```
<div className="App">
  <button onClick={exportToPdf}>Export</button>
  <div id="toRender">
   ------ Pdf print content ------
  <div>
</div>
```

**PDF Export function:**

```
  const exportToPdf = () => {
    let elem = document.getElementById("toRender");
    elem.scrollIntoView();
    h2c(elem).then((canvas) => {

    ---- Logic for exporting pdf ---

    })
  }
```

For complete code please refer the below **working snippet**.

[image: Edit generate pdf with jspdf (forked)]

**Issue:**

The issue is that if we click on export button, then the pdf gets downloaded but we are **unable to select the text from the pdf** .

I could understand the **reason**, that it happens because we are using [addImage()](http://raw.githack.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/module-addImage.html#%7EaddImage) in this line,

```
  pdf.addImage(img, "PNG", 0);
```

But while searching for the related issues here https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/issues , I couldn't get anything helpful..

**Requirement:**

Expectation is that the downloaded pdf is currently looks like an image because of which user unable to select any text from pdf and the need is that user should be able to select the text from pdf.

I am okay to implement any other library to make the html to pdf generation with selectable text as well..

Kindly someone please help me to generate pdf with selectable text instead of image for the above given example. Thanks in advance.

Comment: ```const [state, setState] = useState({ doc : new jsPDF( ) })```
then add text like this ```doc.text("test", x, y, "left")```

Comment: @ZahirMasoodi, How that will add html content? Isn't ```doc.text()``` to add a plain text? I am in the need to add html content..

Comment: Is it necessary to map html content directly?

Comment: @ZahirMasoodi, Yes.. Requirement is that I need to get the same thing which I am getting right now from codesandbox example.. But expectation is that I am in the need to have selectable text instead of image.. Also I could see that ```fromHTML()``` might be useful but it looks like its been deprecated right now..

Comment: Try exporting the file like this ```const myPdf = new File([pdf.output("blob")], "export.pdf", { type: "application/pdf",});``` and then check the file.

Comment: @ZahirMasoodi, I have implemented your code here https://codesandbox.io/s/generate-pdf-with-jspdf-forked-gckn8 in the place of  ```pdf.save()``` but it doesn't work.. Where should I need to implement this code? could you fork my codesandbox and provide solution?

Comment: I made a few changes, can you check!

Comment: @ZahirMasoodi, Where the changes has been made? Please provide me the sandbox link which you changed by using the fork button at top right..

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/generate-pdf-with-jspdf-forked-oq4e5?file=/src/index.js

Comment: @ZahirMasoodi, But here the pdf is not gets downloaded as like the link in my question https://codesandbox.io/s/generate-pdf-with-jspdf-forked-znjxg

Comment: @ZahirMasoodi, On click over the export button, the pdf needs to get downloaded like in the question..

Comment: After clicking export, a link will appear below export button, click on that and check if the text can be copied.

Comment: @ZahirMasoodi, Why the text needs to be copied? User work is only to click on the export button alone and nothing more.. If he click on export button, then pdf needs to be downloaded..

Comment: have you found out a solution to this question ? I am facing a similar issue

Comment: @Erick, No I haven't got the solution yet.

Comment: Hi @ManirajMurugan I've tried fulfiling your requirement, but there are a few caveats.
I have fored your code and added a new button to export PDF. let me know if this will work for you.
https://codesandbox.io/s/generate-pdf-with-jspdf-forked-i1fisi?file=/src/index.js

Comment: same issue. i hope html2canvas library can solve this.