# Link tag changes my history location but then changes back to original home page React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

So I have been having this issue with a project I've been working on for 2 days now and I don't know why. I have used React-router-dom before for my webapps and I have never encountered this issue in all the months I've used React.js I basically have my Switch component, BrowserRouter wrapped around App.js, and everything, but every time I click the link to my new route "/register", the URL would change for a few 2 seconds and then change back to my login homepage. this happens without me doing anything or clicking anything. I've tried changing link tag attribute from to="/register" to href="/register" but that didn't work. It's infuriating, Here's my code:

Index.js

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import {BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom';

ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

App.js

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import { Router, Switch, Route, withRouter, Link} from 'react-router-dom'
import HomePage  from "./components/HomePage";
import Register from "./components/Register"
import Dashboard from "./components/Dashboard"
// import Link from '@material-ui/core/Link';
// import { background } from "./images/7f76e8e7692375107e5998013155af0d.jpg";
// import { TravelerEffect, MosaicGroundEffect, OceanEffect,
//   RainEffect, SeaWaveEffect, SnowFallEffect, SnowFallSlowEffect,
//   SpacingEffect, CloudWaveEffect 
// } from 'react-background-animation'

class App extends Component {

  state = {
    user: {
        email: "",
        username: "",
        is_active: "",
        first_name: "",
        last_name: "",
        bio: "",
        age: "",
        birth_place: "",
        school: "",
        occupation: "",
        what_are_you_seeking_on_site: "",
        profile_pic: null,
        loginErrors: "",
    },
    token: "",
  }

  handleResponse (resp) {
      console.log(resp.user); 
        if (resp.user) {
          localStorage.setItem('token', resp.token)
          this.setState({
            user: resp.user,
            token: resp.token
          }, () => {
            this.props.history.push("/dashboard")
          })
        }
        else {
          alert(resp.error)
        }
      }

      

  componentDidMount(){
    if (localStorage.getItem("token")) {
      fetch('http://localhost:8000/current_user/', {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.token}`
        }
      })
      .then(r => r.json())
      .then(this.handleResp)
    }
  }

  handleRegister(newUser){
        fetch( "http://127.0.0.1:8000/rest-auth/registration/", {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
              'content-type': "application/json"
            }, 
            body: JSON.stringify(newUser)
        })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(this.handleResponse)
      }

      handleLogin(returningUser){
        fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/rest-auth/login/', {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          },
          body: JSON.stringify(returningUser)
        })
          .then(res => res.json())
          .then(this.handleResponse)
      }

  renderRegisterForm = (routerProps) => {
        if (routerProps.location.pathname === "/register") {
            // debugger
          return <Register formName="Register Form" 
            handleSubmit={this.handleRegister}
             />

        }else if(routerProps.location.pathname === "/") {
          return <HomePage formName="Log into Account"
          handleSubmit={this.handleLogin} 
          />
        } 
      }

     

    render() {
      return (
          <div>
              {/* <Link  to="/register">Sign Up</Link> */}
              <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" render={this.renderRegisterForm} />   
                <Route exact path="/register" render={this.renderRegisterForm} /> 
                <Route path="/dashboard" exact component={Dashboard} />
                <Route render={ () => <p>Page not Found</p> } />
              </Switch>
              {/* <Link href="/register"
                    // onClick={this.handleRegisterLinkPage}
                     variant="body1">
                      {"Don't have an account? Sign Up"}
                    </Link> */}
          </div>
      );
    }
      
}

export default withRouter(App);
```

my HomePage.jsx (which is basically my login page)

```
import React from 'react';
import {Redirect} from "react-router-dom"
import Avatar from '@material-ui/core/Avatar';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import FormControlLabel from '@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel';
import Checkbox from '@material-ui/core/Checkbox';
import Link from '@material-ui/core/Link';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import Box from '@material-ui/core/Box';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
// import LockOutlinedIcon from '@material-ui/icons/LockOutlined';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';


const useStyles = theme => ({
        root: {
          height: '100vh',
        },
        image: {
          backgroundImage: 'url(https://source.unsplash.com/random)',
          backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
          backgroundColor:
            theme.palette.type === 'light' ? theme.palette.grey[50] : theme.palette.grey[900],
          backgroundSize: 'cover',
          backgroundPosition: 'center',
        },
        paper: {
          margin: theme.spacing(8, 4),
          display: 'flex',
          flexDirection: 'column',
          alignItems: 'center',
        },
        avatar: {
          margin: theme.spacing(1),
          backgroundColor: theme.palette.secondary.main,
        },
        form: {
          width: '100%', // Fix IE 11 issue.
          marginTop: theme.spacing(1),
        },
        submit: {
          margin: theme.spacing(3, 0, 2),
        },
      });

    function Copyright() {
        return (
          <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary" align="center">
            {'Copyright © '}
            <Link color="inherit" href="https://material-ui.com/">
              Your Website
            </Link>{' '}
            {new Date().getFullYear()}
            {'.'}
          </Typography>
        );
      }

class HomePage extends React.Component {

    // handleRegisterLinkPage = (event) => {
    //   event.preventDefault()
    //   return<Redirect to={"/register"}/>
    //   // debugger
    // }

      render(){

        const {classes} = this.props

        return (
        <Grid container component="main" className={classes.root}>
          <CssBaseline />
          <Grid item xs={false} sm={4} md={7} className={classes.image} />
          <Grid item xs={12} sm={8} md={5} component={Paper} elevation={6} square>
            <div className={classes.paper}>
              <Avatar className={classes.avatar}>
                {/* <LockOutlinedIcon /> */}
              </Avatar>
              <Typography component="h1" variant="h5">
                Sign in
              </Typography>
              <form className={classes.form} noValidate>
                <TextField
                  variant="outlined"
                  margin="normal"
                  required
                  fullWidth
                  id="email"
                  label="Email Address"
                  name="email"
                  autoComplete="email"
                  autoFocus
                />
                <TextField
                  variant="outlined"
                  margin="normal"
                  required
                  fullWidth
                  name="password"
                  label="Password"
                  type="password"
                  id="password"
                  autoComplete="current-password"
                />
                <FormControlLabel
                  control={<Checkbox value="remember" color="primary" />}
                  label="Remember me"
                />
                <Button
                  type="submit"
                  fullWidth
                  variant="contained"
                  color="primary"
                  className={classes.submit}
                >
                  Sign In
                </Button>
                <Grid container>
                  <Grid item xs>
                    {/* <Link href="#" variant="body2">
                      Forgot password?
                    </Link> */}
                  </Grid>
                  <Grid item>
                    <Link href="/register"
                    // onClick={this.handleRegisterLinkPage}
                     variant="body1">
                      <Button> Don't have an account? Sign Up</Button>
                    </Link>{' '}
                  </Grid>
                </Grid>
                <Box mt={5}>
                  <Copyright />
                </Box>
              </form>
            </div>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      );
    }
    

}

export default withStyles(useStyles)(HomePage)
```

And Lastly My register page, which I feel I shouldn't have to show, but here it is anyway

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Avatar from '@material-ui/core/Avatar';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import FormControlLabel from '@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel';
import Checkbox from '@material-ui/core/Checkbox';
import Link from '@material-ui/core/Link';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import Box from '@material-ui/core/Box';
import LockOutlinedIcon from '@material-ui/icons/LockOutlined';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Container from '@material-ui/core/Container';
import TextareaAutosize from '@material-ui/core/TextareaAutosize';
import { MuiPickersUtilsProvider, KeyboardDatePicker } from '@material-ui/pickers';
import FormControl from '@material-ui/core/FormControl';
import FormLabel from '@material-ui/core/FormLabel';
import Radio from '@material-ui/core/Radio';
import RadioGroup from '@material-ui/core/RadioGroup';
import DateFnsUtils from '@date-io/date-fns';

function Copyright() {
  return (
    <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary" align="center">
      {'Copyright © '}
      <Link color="inherit" href="https://material-ui.com/">
        Your Website
      </Link>{' '}
      {new Date().getFullYear()}
      {'.'}
    </Typography>
  );
}

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  paper: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(8),
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  avatar: {
    margin: theme.spacing(1),
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.secondary.main,
  },
  form: {
    width: '100%', // Fix IE 11 issue.
    marginTop: theme.spacing(3),
  },
  submit: {
    margin: theme.spacing(3, 0, 2),
  },
}));

export default function Register() {
  const classes = useStyles(); 


  const [email, setEmail] = useState(" ")
  const [password, setPassword] = useState(" ")
  const [confirmPassword, setConfirmPassword] = useState(" ")
  const [username, setUsername] = useState(" ")
  const [birthPlace, setBirthPlace] = useState(" ")
  const [bio, setBio] = useState(" ")
  const [school, setSchool] = useState(" ")
  const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState(" ")
  const [lastName, setLastName] = useState(" ")
  const [occupation, setOccupation] = useState(" ")
  const [what_are_you_seeking_on_site, setWhat_are_you_seeking_on_site] = useState("Friendship")
  const [age, setAge] = useState(new Date('2014-08-18T21:11:54'));
  const [errors, setErrors] = useState(" ")
  // const [selectedDate, setSelectedDate] = 
  // const [value, setValue] = React.useState('Friendship');

  useEffect(() => {
    if (localStorage.getItem('token') !== null) {
      window.location.replace('http://localhost:3000/dashboard');
    } else {
      window.location.replace('http://localhost:3000/')
    }
  }, []);

  const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const user = {
      email: email,
      username: username,
      birthPlace: birthPlace,
      bio: bio,
      school: school,
      age: age,
      password: password,
      confirmPassword: confirmPassword,
      firstName: firstName,
      lastName: lastName,
      occupation: occupation,
      what_are_you_seeking_on_site: what_are_you_seeking_on_site,
    };

    fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/rest-auth/registration/', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(user)
    })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        if (data.key) {
          localStorage.clear();
          localStorage.setItem('token', data.key);
          window.location.replace('http://localhost:3000/dashboard');
        } else {
          setEmail('');
          setPassword('');
          setConfirmPassword('');
          localStorage.clear();
          setErrors(true);
        }
      });
  };

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setWhat_are_you_seeking_on_site(event.target.value);
  };

  const handleDateChange = (date) => {
    setAge(date);
  };


  return (
    <Container component="main" maxWidth="xs">
      <CssBaseline />
      <div className={classes.paper}>
        <Avatar className={classes.avatar}>
          <LockOutlinedIcon />
        </Avatar>
        <Typography component="h1" variant="h5">
          Sign up
        </Typography>
        <form className={classes.form} onSubmit={handleSubmit}  noValidate>
          <Grid container spacing={2}>
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
              <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
                <TextField
                  autoComplete="username"
                  name="Username"
                  variant="outlined"
                  required
                  fullWidth
                  id="Username"
                  label="Username"
                  autoFocus
                  value={e => setUsername(e.target.value)}
                />
              </Grid>
              <TextField
                autoComplete="fname"
                name="firstName"
                variant="outlined"
                required
                fullWidth
                id="firstName"
                label="First Name"
                autoFocus
                value={e => setFirstName(e.target.value)}
              />
            </Grid>
            
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
              <TextField
                variant="outlined"
                required
                fullWidth
                id="lastName"
                label="Last Name"
                name="lastName"
                value={e => setLastName(e.target.value)}
              />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12}>
              <TextField
                variant="outlined"
                required
                fullWidth
                id="email"
                label="Email Address"
                name="email"
                value={e => setEmail(e.target.value)}
              />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12}>
              <TextField
                variant="outlined"
                required
                fullWidth
                name="password"
                label="Password"
                type="password"
                id="password"
                value={e => setPassword(e.target.value)}
                />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12}>
              <TextField
                variant="outlined"
                required
                fullWidth
                name="Confirm password"
                label="Confirm Password"
                type="password2"
                id="password2"
                value={e => setConfirmPassword(e.target.value)}
              />
            </Grid>

            <Grid item xs={12}>
              <TextareaAutosize 
              aria-label="minimum height" 
              fullWidth
              label="Bio" 
              rowsMin={3} 
              placeholder="Minimum 3 rows" 
              value={e => setBio(e.target.value)}
              />
            </Grid>

            <Grid item xs={12}>
              <TextField
                variant="outlined"
                required
                fullWidth
                name="Birth Place"
                label="Where were you born"
                id="birthPlace"
                value={e => setBirthPlace(e.target.value)}
              />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12}>
              <TextField
                variant="outlined"
                required
                fullWidth
                name="School"
                label="School"
                id="School"
                value={e => setSchool(e.target.value)}
              />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12}>
              <TextField
                variant="outlined"
                required
                fullWidth
                name="Occupation"
                label="Occupation"
                id="Occupation"
                value={e => setOccupation(e.target.value)}
              />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12}>
            <FormControl component="fieldset">
              <FormLabel component="legend">What are you here for</FormLabel>
              <RadioGroup aria-label="what_are_you_seeking_on_site" name="what_are_you_seeking_on_site" value={what_are_you_seeking_on_site} onChange={handleChange}>
              <FormControlLabel value="Dating" control={<Radio />} label="Dating" />
              <FormControlLabel value="Friendship" control={<Radio />} label="Friendship" />
              <FormControlLabel value="Networking" control={<Radio />} label="Networking" />
              <FormControlLabel value="Business" control={<Radio />} label="Business" />
            </RadioGroup>
            </FormControl>
            </Grid>

            <Grid item xs={12}>
            <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
              <KeyboardDatePicker
                margin="normal"
                id="date-picker-dialog"
                label="Date picker dialog"
                format="MM/dd/yyyy"
                // value={selectedDate}
                onChange={handleDateChange}
                KeyboardButtonProps={{
                  'aria-label': 'change date',
                }}
                value={e => setAge(e.target.value)}
              />
            </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12}>
              <FormControlLabel
                control={<Checkbox value="allowExtraEmails" color="primary" />}
                label="I want to receive inspiration, marketing promotions and updates via email."
              />
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
          <Button
            type="submit"
            fullWidth
            variant="contained"
            color="primary"
            className={classes.submit}
          >
            Sign Up
          </Button>
          <Grid container justify="flex-end">
            <Grid item>
              <Link href="/" variant="body2">
                Already have an account? Sign in
              </Link>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </form>
      </div>
      <Box mt={5}>
        <Copyright />
      </Box>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

Please Help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your `Register` component mounts you've an `useEffect` hook that runs and either bounces the user to "/dashboard" or "/".

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (localStorage.getItem('token') !== null) {
    window.location.replace('http://localhost:3000/dashboard');
  } else {
    window.location.replace('http://localhost:3000/')
  }
}, []);
```

If the token exists and isn't `null` then bouncing a user to the dashboard path is probably acceptable. You may not want to bounce users to the homepage when they are trying to register so you can likely remove the `else` branch entirely.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (localStorage.getItem('token') !== null) {
    window.location.replace('http://localhost:3000/dashboard');
  }
}, []);
```

Comment: I feel, you would be the right person to help me in this question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66950166/select-text-in-pdf Could you please kindly look into this question as I am totally stuck with my work..